# factor $\sum_i^4 p_i x^i$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

The polynomial $f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^4 p_i x^i $ whose real coefficients are:
$$
          p_4 = (L^2 + s^2) ^2  \\
               p_3= -4 L^2  (L^2 + s^2)\\
              p_2 = 6  L^4 + 2   L^2s^2  \\
              p_1 = -4  L^4  \\
p_0= L^4 - V^2\\
$$
can be factored as $ \left[   \left(L^2 + s^2 \right)x^2-2L^2x+L^2+V \right]  \left[   \left(L^2 + s^2 \right)x^2-2L^2x+L^2-V \right]$. However, it's difficult to factor the polynomial with the following coefficients:
$$
          p_4 = (L^2 + s^2) ^2  \\
               p_3= -4 L^2  (L^2 + s^2)\\
              p_2 = 6  L^4 + 2   L^2s^2+L^2-s^2  \\
              p_1 = -4  L^4 -2L^2 \\
p_0= L^4 +L^2+ \frac{1}{4}- V^2\\
$$
I find the negative $-s^2$ term in $p_2$ is tricky (Factorization becomes very easy when $p_2 = 6  L^4 + 2   L^2s^2+L^2+s^2$ instead). Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is the same as solving the quartic equation - which is a complicated task. You might want to share the context and the actual problem that you're trying to solve. Maybe there's a solution that doesn't involve factoring the polynomial?

Comment: Thanks! skyking. The actual problem is to study the properties of the roots in terms of the parameters $L, s, V$, which is equivalent to factor the polynomial. Hopefully there are some heuristics to ease this particular problem. I already find some patterns, for example, the terms $L^4, -4L^4, 6L^4, -4L^4, L^4$ in $p_i$ are the binomial numbers.